# problems with include in EF Core 6 against an existing database

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have this Model which is a mapping of existing tables in a SAP database (where there is not a single relationship defined between the tables) that I want to attack via EF Core and LINQ

[image]

I have coded the relationships many-to-many

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Actividad>().ToTable("OCLG");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Proyecto>().ToTable("OPRJ");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Empleado>().ToTable("OHEM");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("OUSR");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Fase>().ToTable("[@ITAPROYSEG]");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Actividad>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.U_Proy, a.U_Fase, a.AttendUser});

        modelBuilder.Entity<Actividad>()
            .HasOne(a => a.Proyecto)
            .WithMany(p => p.Actividades)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.U_Proy);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Actividad>()
            .HasOne(a => a.Fase)
            .WithMany(f => f.Actividades)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.U_Fase);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Actividad>()
            .HasOne(a => a.Usuario)
            .WithMany(u => u.Actividades)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.AttendUser);
    }
```

And the relationship one-to-one

```
public class Empleado
{       
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    
    [Key]
    public string U_CodEmpl { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string NombreCompleto=>$"{FirstName} {MiddleName} {LastName}";

    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName ="smallint")]
    public int Internal_K { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Empleado")]
    public string User_Code { get; set; }

    public Empleado Empleado { get; set; }

    public List<Actividad> Actividades { get; set; }

}
```

When I query this in database directly

[image]

I get 479 rows

Now I try it in my Solution

```
void GetActividadesByEmpleadoYAñoRaw(string codigoSAPEmpleado, int año)
{
 var  empleado=_context.Empleados.Include(e=>e.Usuario).FirstOrDefault(e=>e.U_CodEmpl==codigoSAPEmpleado);
```

When I debug here I get this

[image]

Include gives me the Usuarioassociated but If I try to receive the Actividades associated to the Usuario

```
void GetActividadesByEmpleadoYAñoRaw(string codigoSAPEmpleado, int año)
```

{

```
var empleado = _context.Empleados.Include(e => e.Usuario).ThenInclude(u => u.Actividades).FirstOrDefault(e => e.U_CodEmpl == codigoSAPEmpleado);
```

[image]

I get only 143 rows

If I try a FromRaw query

```
var empleado = _context.Empleados.Include(e => e.Usuario).ThenInclude(u => u.Actividades).FirstOrDefault(e => e.U_CodEmpl == codigoSAPEmpleado);
var actividades = _context.Actividades
    .FromSqlRaw(@"select AttendUser, U_Proy, U_Fase, Recontact, Durtype, Duration
                                from oclg
                                where AttendUser=" + empleado.Usuario.Internal_K + "  and year(recontact)=" + año +
                                "order by Recontact, U_Proy, U_Fase").ToList();
```

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably an issue with your One-to-One relationship between Employee and User. By default EF will expect a HasOne.WithOne to be joining on the PK of both tables so you might have a situation where your Employee.User is picking a User record with a UserID matching the EmployeeId rather than using the Employee.UserId (or User.EmployeeId, it's not clear from your description) If you have something like a UserID on the Employee table, use the HasForeignKey to nominate it. (A shadow property with no property in the entity is fine)

Comment: @StevePy Empleado has [Key] Annotation in U_CodEmpl and Usuario has [ForeignKey("Empleado")] in UserCode. These are the fields that the relationships and in fact the Include from Empleado gives me the associated Usuario so I assumed that the one-to-one relationship was working just by convention

Comment: Hmm, the next thing to check would be that the connection string used by the DbContext at runtime is pointing at the same DB instance that you are checking against.  Where you have a breakpoint to get the Actividades, add a `var connectionString = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;` then verify that value against the database you are checking. Often connection strings get updated in Assembly web/app.config files but miss that at runtime the connection string will be pulled from the main app .exe.config/web.config or appsettings.json copy.

Comment: I have verified that I am accessing the correct database. I have created the one-to-may relationship with FluentAPI in the OnModelCreating but I keep getting different data than what I get by directly executing the SQL statements in SQL Management Studio against the database directly. From 479 Activities I go to 143 and I can't find the reason. It only occurs to me that when I am attacking a database where these relationships do not exist, the fact of creating them in my model is not working.

Comment: Log generated SQL and everything should be uncovered.